# Formbuilder Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to play with jQuery drag and drop for my own experimentation and I was wondering if could get some help: I am needing the controls drop down and text to show in the drag controls here area and allow them to be sortable. I have tried to get the controls to pin to the containment `div`.

However, it is still allowing it to drag out side the main conatainment `div`:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>draggable demo</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <style>
      #draggable {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: #ccc;
      }
      </style>
      <style type="text/css">
    .movecontrol {cursor:move}

    </style>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="draggable">Drag me</div>

    <style>
      .draggable {   padding: 5px; float: left; margin: 0 10px 10px 0; font-size: .9em; border:none; }
      .ui-widget-header p, .ui-widget-content p { margin: 0; }
      #snaptarget { height: 140px; }
       #containment-wrapper { width: 95%; height:150px; border:2px solid #ccc; padding: 10px; }

      </style>
      <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ snap: true });
        $( "#draggable2" ).draggable({ snap: ".ui-widget-header" });
        $( "#draggable3" ).draggable({ snap: ".ui-widget-header", snapMode: "outer" });
        $( "#draggable4" ).draggable({ grid: [ 20, 20 ] ,containment: "parent"});
        $( "#draggable5" ).draggable({ grid: [ 80, 80 ] });
      });
      </script>

       <div id="containment-wrapper">

       Drop all your form controls here

     </div>




     </div>
     <div id="containment-wrapper">

    <div id="draggable" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
      <SELECT id="name" >
      <option>Test</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div id="draggable2" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
       <input type="text" name="lname" ><br>
    </div>

    <div id="draggable3" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
     <input type="text" name="lname" ><br>  <p>I only snap to the outer edges of the big box</p>
    </div>
    <div class="draggable ui-widget-content">
    <p id="draggable5" class="ui-widget-header">I'm contained within my parent</p>
      </div>




     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I did [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgpr5put/), but it's not working as expected.

Second Attempt
This allows me to sort and drop but how do I make them the actual elements I want them to be, for example, in a textbox.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Draggable + Sortable</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  ul { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; }
  li { margin: 5px; padding: 5px; width: 150px; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
      revert: true
    });
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
      connectToSortable: "#sortable",
      helper: "clone",
      revert: "invalid"
    });
    $( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();

     $( "#draggable2" ).draggable({
      connectToSortable: "#sortable",
      helper: "clone",
      revert: "invalid"
    });
    $( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

 <div style="float:left;">
<ul>
  <li id="draggable" class="ui-state-highlight">Text Box</li>
</ul>
<ul> 
 <li id="draggable2" class="ui-state-highlight">Radio Button</li>
</ul>
</div>
 <div style="float:left;">
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```